# Diagonalizing a matrix perturbatively

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Say we have two matrices $H$ and $J$, both of which are diagonalizable. Let $\lambda$ be some small parameter. What's the best method for diagonalizing the sum $H + \lambda J$, working perturbatively in $\lambda$? (say, to $O(\lambda^2)$)